# Has anyone successfully implemented OpenID with Mono?

Tags: linux, mono, dotnetopenauth

I am working on a web project where I'd like to use OpenID with Mono on Linux.  DotNetOpenAuth has wiki on for configuring OpenID with XSP, but it also [listed known issues that have yet to be](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/wiki/mono) resolved such as throw an error when using a https certificate.

What has been your experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://wrench.mono-project.com/ is an MVC site I wrote that runs on Mono 2.6.1 using mod_mono and Apache.  It uses DotNetOpenAuth.  I think all you have to do is use a ~recent version of Mono, and compile the DotNetOpenAuth dll from their "mono2" branch in git.

Comment: The link seems to have been taken down. Could you please update it? I don't see a mono2 branch in git.

Comment: @capdragon The bracnh is there, try https://github.com/aarnott/dotnetopenid/tree/mono2.  That said, this didn't work for me under Mono 2.10

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, XSP is only a lightweight server for getting started with Mono/ASP.NET; not recommended for use in a production environment.

If you're serious about ASP.NET on Mono in a production environment, I'd set up a proper Apache/mod_mono test environment to run your ASP.NET projects in.

Comment: Thanks - any input on OpenId with mod_mono?