# Run DotNetOpenAuth on mono/linux

Tags: linux, mono, dotnetopenauth

I have tried for some time with no luck to find a version of DotNetOpenAuth which would work on Mono/Linux combo. The source and binaries which I found in their page/git page contain some References to dll files not supported by mono.
On the other hand I have heard that it is possible to use it and even seen a page on which it is said, that it is done with such a combo.

Is it possible to run DotNetOpenAuth on mono/linux?
If yes, then what are the steps to do so?
If not, could you suggest any laternatives for providing openid/oauth logins on mono/linux?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to go to their git repository and use the 'mono2' branch, as it has the things Mono doesn't support removed.

[Has anyone successfully implemented OpenID with Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117341/has-anyone-successfully-implemented-openid-with-mono)

Comment: I would add that even with that, DotNetOpenAuth cannot *build* within Mono.  It can only *run* and be referenced from within Mono.  So build the mono2 branch in Windows, then copy the DLL to to Linux and add it to your web site there.

Comment: Do I need to build it on windows/mono or windows/.net? Also, maybe some one knows, where I can get such already compiled dll, if I don't have a windows development computer handy?

Comment: I have tried to build mono2 branch of dotnetopenid from github (on VS 2008, .net 3.5) and referenced DotNetOpenAuth.dll, but I'm getting exception during authentication (https://gist.github.com/794732).

Comment: Ok, I got it to build at least (still have to test it). I had to build the mono2 branch on windows VS 2008, but before that remove dependencies from the source for System.Web.Mobile (There is one none critical class using it). After that the dll works in monodevelop on mono/ubuntu. If you could add this information to the answer, then I could accept it - if not I will have to answer myself later.

Comment: @krisa: under which version of framework have you managed to get it working?

Comment: @yojimbo87 - version 2.6.7. Unfortunately I need the OAuth 2.0 functionality, which is not there in the mono2 branch. And oauth2 branch cannot be compiled on VS2008 and requires VS2010. I really dont understand why isnt there a clean base library, which doesn't depend on Mobile forms etc.

Comment: Under Mono 2.10, it looks like the Application.Lock() doesn't do anything because an exception is thrown when it's time to Unlcok().  Revising this code got me past this error.